# DAX count rows but not for future dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've got 3 tables. First is a date table that only has dates. Second is my actual values and third is my projected. Actuals and Projected are both related to the date table (1 to many single direction)

Trying to plot actual vs projected on a line graph, using the dates column from the dates table and a measure from each of the other two. This is my measure for actual values: count = calculate(counta(actual[product]))+0. The issue is then the graph shows 0s for all future dates where I only want my projected line to show up. Is there a different measure I can use to not show the 0 for the future date and be blank instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

count = calculate(counta(actual[product]),
'Date'[Date] <= max(Date[Date)
)

Please note that Date: your calendar table,
[Date ]  is column in side the Date table.

Please let me know if your issue has been resolved.